# android:layout_alignBaseline attribute unexpected behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to design very simple registration activity layout, using RelativeLayout.
To align the text labels with the text to be filled, I'm using 'layout_alignBaseline' attribute between the TextView label and the EditView to its right.

The following layout works as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Register Here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRegisterFirstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/editRegisterFirstName"
        android:text="First Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editRegisterFirstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/textRegisterFirstName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textRegisterFirstName"
        android:layout_below="@id/textTitle"
        android:inputType="text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the result:

[image]

BUT

when I'm switching between layout_alignBaseline attribute of the EditText element and the layout_below attribute of the TextView (with the necessary changes of names) as following:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textRegisterFirstName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/textTitle"
    android:text="First Name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editRegisterFirstName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/textRegisterFirstName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textRegisterFirstName"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textRegisterFirstName"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

The EditText element "jumps" out the screen:

[image]

(The blue rectangular it android studio indication of it's position)

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see the same behavior on an actual device? What OS version?

Comment: Where do you want to put the Edit text field? Above or bellow First Name?

Comment: @alanv - I tried it on real device yesterday and it saw the same behavior, now tried it again and on the real device it was rendered fine. Maybe something on my env is broken.

Comment: @diogojme - It should be to its right (as in the first image)

Comment: Just remove this attribute layout_alignBaseline, and add android:layout_below="@id/textTitle"